# Passing JSON array to view CodeIgniter through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having a problem trying to pass a JSON array from my controller to the view to be able to produce a chart using chart js.
I've tried echoing the JSON from the controller and it gets the necessary values.

In my PHP file, there is an ajax call that gets data using a function in the controller.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php/Sales/topClients",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(parsedData[0].Name);
        var clientname = [];
        var orqty = [];

        for(var i in parsedData){
            clientname.push(parsedData[i].Name);
            orqty.push(parsedData[i].Quantity);
        }
        var chartdata= {
            labels: clientname,
            datasets:[
                {
                    label: 'Ordered Quantity',
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(231, 76, 60,0.7)', 
                        'rgba(52, 152, 219,0.7)', 
                        'rgba(46, 204, 113,0.7)', 
                        'rgba(230, 126, 34,0.7)',
                        'rgba(155, 89, 182,0.7)',
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(231, 76, 60,1.0)', 
                        'rgba(52, 152, 219,1.0)', 
                        'rgba(46, 204, 113,1.0)', 
                        'rgba(230, 126, 34,1.0)',
                        'rgba(155, 89, 182,1.0)',
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: orqty
                }
            ]               
        };
        Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.beginAtZero=true;
        Chart.defaults.global.title.display= true;

        var ctx= $("#RMCanvas");
        var barGraph= new Chart(ctx,{
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartdata
        });
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

This is the controller (Inventory)

```
public function topGoods(){
    $top5fgsold= $this -> Inventory_Model -> getTopGoods();
    echo json_encode($top5fgsold);
    //$this->load->view("SA_Home-Latest");
}
```

This is the model: Inventory_Model

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

class Sales_Model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function getTopClients(){    
        $this->db-> select("clients.ClientName, SUM(salesinvoicedetails.orderedQuantity) as q");
        $this->db         -> from("salesinvoicedetails");
        $this->db         -> join ("salesinvoice", "salesinvoicedetails.InvoiceNo = salesinvoice.InvoiceNo");
        $this->db         -> join("clients", "clients.ClientNo = salesinvoice.ClientNo");
        $this->db         -> where("salesinvoice.Status", 2);
        $this->db         -> where("OrderDate >=", " DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)");
        $this->db         -> where("OrderDate <= NOW()");
        $this->db         ->group_by("1");
        $this->db         ->order_by("q", "desc");
        $this->db         ->limit(5);

        $topclientresult= $this-> db -> get();
        return $topclientresult-> result_array();
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: your question is not clear, what is your problem, what do you want expect.
If there is any error you should show it

Answer (score 1):

You should use dataType:"json" in you ajax method.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
                url: url
                type: 'GET', 
                dataType: 'json', 

                success: function() {

                    //your code
                },
                error: function() {
                    //your code
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check if your service working fine, I can see that you using a GET method, so if you put the link in browser you will see a JSON array, if you can't see anything the problem is in your back-end, then you need to check your PHP code.

Second, if you recieve the JSON in your browser, then you can make a request using AJAX,

you can see the result print the data result in console:

```
success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
```

For view the result you need to enable the console using `F12` then you recharge the page and verify if the JSON appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set response type - json to get a json reponse.
By adding the line **dataType:"json"**

```
url: "index.php/Sales/topClients",
method: "GET",
dataType:"json"
```